# How to pause and resume a gif using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html, gif

I am creating a tool where you can record a page with Graphic Interchange Format (GIF), but when I use phantom js to record it is not working as expected hence is there a good practice/approach to pause and/or resume a gif?  Just like people do in 9gag.com?

For an instance, I would like to to play 1 frame every second?

Comment: Please add your code to the question. What did you try sofar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot currently pause or play a gif explicitly in most browsers. With that being said, you can use an external "tool" or program to separate the images automatically and display them like that?

Comment: Yeah , can you name an tool that you might have came over somewhere?

Comment: It is CLI based so can easily be integrated with system calls in most languages.